# isn't a float4 multiplied by _World2Object a 4by4 matrix?

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine, shader

I am studying unity shader, but a line of code confuses me goes:

```
float3 normalDirection = normalize(mul(float4(v.normal,0.0),_World2Object).xyz);
```

isn't the result of a float4 multiplied by a _World2Object(which is a 4x4 matrix) also a 4x4 matrix? but it seems like the result is a float4 and then converted to a float3 by accessing the .xyz property.

and is there any predefined properties for accessing 2 dimensional matrices like .xyz?

many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may multiply vector by matrix as well as matrix by vector.

The first case called left- or pre-multiplication and vector is expressed in row-major order (1x4). The second case is right- or post-multiplication where vector is expressed in column-major order (4x1).

Lets consider matrix (4x4) as a basis of X,Y,Z and W vectors. Then in row-major order matrix will be written as

```
 X1,X2,X3,X4
 Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4
 Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4
 W1,W2,W3,W4
```

while in column-major order the same matrix will be written as

```
 X1,Y1,Z1,W1
 X2,Y2,Z2,W2
 X3,Y3,Z3,W3
 X4,Y4,Z4,W4
```

So the order of multiplication (V.M vs M.V) is depended solely on order of matrix. In your example the matrix is written in row-major order. Since its 4x4 matrix, it represent full affine transformation in 3D-space (rotation, scale and transformation). Therefore to multiply a **vector** by this matrix you must provide row-vector (X,Y,Z,0). Note that if you want to transform a **point** you must provide row-vector (X,Y,Z,1).

Regarding the rest of your question, there is a built-in swizzle operator: .xyzw or .rgba for vectors. This operator allows the components of a vector to be rearranged and also replicated (.xxxx , .wzyx , .rrra, et.c). There are no sqizzle operators for matrices.